# Low current input source - current limiting resistor for z-diode needed?

Tags: zener

I have a very low current input source (tiny solar cells) with a maximum short circuit current of 80µA which are loading a supercapacitor (1F/5.5V). To protect the supercapacitor from damage I added a z-diode with a value of 5.1V and 500mW. Since the output current of the solar cells is so low, can I ommit the current limiting resistor for this diode?

Answer (score 1):

On one hand, if the resistor is omitted, your supercap protection will work more reliably - allowing high voltage spikes to last for shorter periods of time by passing more current though the Zener. This could in turn destroy the diode.

On the other hand, by including the resistor, you will save the diode from self-destructing, but expose the capacitor to longer over-voltages.

Anyway, I would leave the resistor out, since it's the capacitor you want to save, not the diode.

Comment: Yes, I think the same. Max voltage is 6V so the wattage is tiny... Thanks for your thoughts.